# Howto determine order of displayed columns in a datagridview binded to a datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0

Is there a way to determine the order of the columns displayed in 
a datagridview when binding it to a datasource whitch contains an 
underlying IList ?
I thought there was a specific property attribute for this purpose
but can't recall what it actually was.

eg:

```
 public void BindToGrid(IList<CustomClass> list)
        {
            _bindingSource.DataSource = list;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource.DataSource;
        }
```

Type binded should be something like this

```
class CustomClass
{
        bool _selected = false;
        //[DisplayOrder(0)]
        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set { _selected = value; }
        }

        string _name;
         //[DisplayOrder(2)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        string _value;
         //[DisplayOrder(1)]
        public string Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }
}
```

Edit:
I would like to add that I rather not want to add the columns manually to columns list in the designer. I'd like to keep this as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `DataGridView` specify an actual list of columns instead of allowing it to auto-databind. You can do this in Design View in Visual Studio by selecting the control and adding the columns. Make sure you specify in each column which property it should bind to. Then you can rearrange the columns any way you want as well as do other customizations.

I think that the `DisplayOrder` attribute is relatively new and probably not supported in the `DataGridView` control.

Answer (score 1):

The display order of the columns in the `DataGridView` is determined by the `DisplayIndex` properties of the `DataGridViewColumn`-s. You would have to set these properties on the columns of the grid, in order to change their order.

I also agree with Eilon's answer: you can create the list of the columns yourself, instead of auto-databinding, and that way you can determine the order in which they will be displayed.

Comment: If you do try setting `DisplayIndex` be sure you set it after setting the `DataGridView`'s `DataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is a functionality that .Net Offers, but if you just change the order of your properties in the class, the grid renders the columns in the same order.

The below two classes will render in the order they are typed in the class. Strange!!

```
class CustomClass
{
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

class CustomClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}       
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
}
```